# Which file system is the best one in Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems

I often use ext3. But the performance is not good if there are thousands of files in one directory. Deleting old files also take a very long time. I want to switch XFS, but someone said that it was not stable and he ever met some serious crash problems.

I hear btrfs is good. Can someone introduce it with his own experience? And how about ext4?

Thaks!

Answer (score 3):

just [stumbled upon](http://tytso.livejournal.com/64071.html):

[image]

Comment: +1, although I do wish that there'd be one including more than just `ext*` and `xfs. [There are indeed **many** more than that](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxClustersAndFileSystems.html).

Comment: @akira, How could XFS be so fast? Don't they do many redundancy checks to ensure data integrity?

Answer (score 2):

My experiences:

- **reiserfs**: The best until ext4 came along. Very fast and stable at most operations.
- **ext3**: Rock solid. The best choice for predictability.
- **ext4**: Numerous bugs. Use with the latest kernel. Best all round choice since Lucid.
- **btrfs**: Not ready. There are some really stupid bugs that will trip you up. (Such as corrupting on ENOSPC).
- **xfs**: Good for storage. Never had a proper need for it. Reiserfs and ext4 are better in every way.

Just to emphasise: Use **ext4** unless you're using an old kernel, in which case use **ext3**.

Comment: reiserfs is not a good file system. It has edge cases where the implementers chose speed over correctness, yielding a file system that can corrupt itself, or at least your data, on unexpected power-down. It's OK for a few applications that can miss data, such as news spools, but for reliability ext3/ext4 and XFS beat it hands down. XFS is a good file system, particularly for large files, but it is a port to Linux from IRIX.

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have mentioned ZFS.  True, on Linux it's only available as a FUSE filesystem, so you'd have to use something else like ext4 for your root, but for large file systems and RAID systems IMHO it really can't be beaten.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS